# Using reflection, dynamically load require module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

So I have a small requirejs application that needs to create instances of a dynamic list of classes in runtime.  Basically, reflection.  I've done quite a bit of reading, but I've been finding a lot of references to Typescript, which I'm not using.

The principal idea is that before requirejs is ready, an array is loaded with a list of classes that will be required.  This array is given to requirejs after its main entry point and I hope to create an instance for each entry.

I have done some reading of Ben Nadal's blog here http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2320-extending-classes-in-a-modular-javascript-application-architecture-using-requirejs.htm and I like his pattern and think this would work well for some of the modules I plan to dynamically create.

I had a thought that I could do something like this:-

```
_.each(loader, function(dep) {
            require([dep.name]);
        });
```

With `loader` being the global loaded with the array list.  This doesn't create an instance of the dependency though, which is what I want in this case, like so:-

```
new Carousel('Delboy');
new Carousel('Rodney');
new Carousel('Grandad');
```

This, in this example, would create an instance of 3 new carousels, each with a name as passed in via the constructor.  I think I am missing something in my understanding, help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each resolved AMD dependency is an AMD module, which means that it's either a singleton object or a function. In the post by Ben Nadel which you referred to, a distinction is made between "definitions" and "instances". A definition is a singleton, and from a definition (function) you can create multiple instances. In Ben's terminology, RequireJS will only give you the definitions, and it is up to you to create the instances.

So, the following should work for what you're trying to do:

```
define('Carousel', [], function (name) {
    this.name = name;
});
var loader = {};
var carousels = ['Delboy','Rodney','Grandad'];

carousels.forEach(function (carouselName) {
    require(['Carousel'], function (Carousel) {
        loader[carouselName] = new Carousel(carouselName);
    });
});
```